# hook_page_alter and trying to change the '#theme_wrappers' property

Tags: routes, theming

I'm going a bit Drupal crazy trying to change the '#theme_wrappers' property of certain blocks in my sidebar region. I am able to set it using hook_page_alter and can dpm() it and confirm it is being set, but it never calls the function I point it to:

```
 $element = $vars['page']['sidebar_first'];

  foreach($element as &$elements){
    if (array_key_exists('#block', $elements)){
      $menuBlock = (array) $elements['#block'];
      if ($menuBlock['delta'] == "navigation" || $menuBlock['module'] == "menu"){
        $elements['#theme_wrappers'] = array('wet4_menu_tree__menu_sidebar');
      }
    }
  }

=====================

function wet4_menu_tree__menu_sidebar(&$variables) {
  dpm($variables);
    return '<ul class="list-group menu list-unstyled">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that the elements array you are assigning the wrapper to are not actually being rendered? Also can you confirm that your line setting the theme wrapper is actually running?

Comment: Do you have any errors in any of your logs (watchdog, apache)?

Answer (score 1):

As I commented above, the issue was that I was missing the & before $vars in this line:

```
$element = $vars['page']['sidebar_first'];
```

It was not creating a reference so it wasn't actually setting my '#theme_wrappers' property.

Answer (score 0):

The theme function is menu_tree and menu_tree__menu_sidebar is a more specific version.

So the theme name you need to use is menu_tree__menu_sidebar. Like this:

```
$elements['#theme_wrappers'] = array('menu_tree__menu_sidebar');
```

Then the theme system will search form implementations of that and find your  wet4_menu_tree__menu_sidebar function.

Comment: Thanks, rooby. I have also tried that to no avail.

Comment: Did you flush your drupal cache after adding the theme override function?

Comment: Yes sir, I've learned that lesson the hard way.

Comment: I've seen the specific double underscore theme functions not work for theme_links (see https://www.drupal.org/node/2321789) but that is an edge case and hopefully it isn't happening elsewhere. If you try using just 'menu_tree' as the theme function and changing your definition to  wet4_menu_tree does that run?

Comment: I actually figured out what the issue was: Missing the & before $vars here - $element = $vars['page']['sidebar_first']; It was not creating a reference. Thanks for the help!